# Eloquent morphTo()->withTrashed() stopped working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a polymorphic relationship set up in an `OrderItem` model, where `saleable`  can be a few different models.

I've set it up like any other relationship:

```
public function saleable()
{
    return $this->morphTo()->withTrashed();
}
```

This used to work fine, now all of a sudden it doesn't work and it throws the error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed()
```

I don't understand why it would have stopped working, possibly due to a composer update which may have updated Laravel. I'm on v5.2.35. Any idea why it would have stopped working and what other solutions do I have?

**UPDATE**

Works fine with v5.2.33 and earlier. May be a bug, I've [opened an issue on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13886)

Comment: Your question helped me solve my issue. Needed to grab the trashed models within polymorphic. Gracias!

Answer (score 8):

I dug through the code and found a solution! This solution is for my issue, where some models can be soft deleted and others cannot.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;
//...
public function mySometimesSoftDeletableRelation(){
    return $this->morphTo()->withoutGlobalScope(SoftDeletingScope::class);
}
```

At its core, `withTrashed` uses `unset`, which doesn't care if it's unsetting something which isn't set, so this removes the SoftDeletingScope on those models which have it, and does nothing for others.

Comment: i have this problem again in laravel 8.0, even tho it was stated this was fixed in 5.2 or so. this solution helped me.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I could imagine is that you removed SoftDelete trait for the object, so it's not loaded any more or you've added `boot` method that doesn't inherit from parent (so it won't load proper methods from this trait)

**EDIT**

It seems to be a bug introduced in v5.2.34. It seems to be fixed in this PR https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13828

**EDIT**

It should be fixed at the moment. v5.2.36 has been released.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Each `saleable` model has the SoftDeletes trail, I wouldn't need one on the actual `OrderItem` itself as it's not relevant. I haven't added a `boot` method to the models either.

Comment: @Wasim Have you changed any code before updating to latest version? Do you remember what version of 5.2 were you using before update?

Comment: To be honest I haven't tested that bit of code in a while so I wouldn't be sure. Let me rollback laravel framework version and see if I can get it working

Comment: Ok it breaks with version 5.2.34. Works fine with 5.2.33 and earlier. I can't see this being removed without notice so I assume it must be a bug?

Comment: @Wasim I think you are right. It's a bug. when you look at changelog https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/CHANGELOG.md for 5.2.34 you will see "Apply constraints to morphTo relationships when using eager loading" . Probably it has been fixed here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13828/commits but it's not released as 5.2.36 yet.

Comment: @Wasim 5.2.36 has been released. Is the bug fixed when you update to this version?