# Laravel Eager Load Multiple Polymorphic Relationships - some soft deletes, some not

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have several models that contain a polymorphic field. These poly fields contain four or five relationships each, some are soft deleteable, some are not. I'm running into a 'damned if you do, damned if you don't' problem and not sure how to solve.

If I load with a call to eager loading without including trashed on the models that have softdeletes:

```
$deptRisks = \App\DeptRisk::with(['owner', 'riskable']);
```

I will get the following error on those models that have been soft-deleted:

> Trying to get property of non-object

If I load WITH the withTrashed for the softdeletes:

```
$deptRisks = \App\DeptRisk::with(['owner', 'riskable' => function ($query) {
        $query->withTrashed();
}]);
```

I will get the following error on those models that have NOT been set up as soft-deletes:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed()

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm spinning in circles. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Try defining your morph relation like this (only tested in Laravel 5.8)

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;

class DeptRisk extends Model {
    function riskable(): MorphTo {
        return $this->morphsTo()->withoutGlobalScope(SoftDeletingScope::class);
    }
}
```

This will make sure all soft-deleted morphed relations are returned.

Or if you don't want to make this global for your model, remove the global scope within your eager loading callback like so:

```php
<?php

use App\DeptRisk;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;

$deptRisks = DeptRisk::with([
    'owner',
    'riskable' => function ($query) {
        $query->withoutGlobalScope(SoftDeletingScope::class);
    }
]);
```

Comment: This answer is underappreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, but not a solution.  I do not believe this is possible with Laravel currently, which is unfortunate.

One work-around would be to enforce this at the relationship level.  IE make two separate relationships, riskable and riskableWithTrashed.  You could then call both within the loading process, one without the closure, the other with.  This would successfully load all the models, but there are several disadvantages, worst of which would be always having to create if-check logic around using the collection (one field would essentially become two).

I chose not to use this, but rather went back and made the non-soft-delete polymorphic relations into soft deletes.  Not an efficient solution, but after two days of failing to combine, it was successful.

Comment: Update over a year later.  I had this problem again and again, and found my own question when hunting for an answer LOL.  Still can't find a workable solution like ifHasSotfDelete()->thenQuery() or sometsuch.  Bottom line, still using the last paragraph above as the 'solution'.

Comment: I'm having the same problem now, and yeah, no solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try something like this when you define the relationship:

```
public function riskable() {
    $builder = $this->morphTo();

    if (method_exists($builder, 'withTrashed')) {
        $builder->withTrashed();
    }

    return $builder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too tried the suggested solution

```
public function riskable() {
    $builder = $this->morphTo();

    if (method_exists($builder, 'withTrashed')) {
        $builder->withTrashed();
    }

    return $builder;
}
```

Unfortunately, $builder, wasn't the actual model, so I couldn't check for the withTrashed method.

On 5.4, php 7.1 the most elegant solution I found was to wrap the attempt at ->withTrashed in a try catch.

```
public function riskable() {
    $morphTo = $this->morphTo();

    try {
        return $morphTo->withTrashed();
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        return $morphTo;
    }

}
```

I ran into this when loading a polymorphic relationship when appending data to the model.

This worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which worked for me, while the solutions here didn't work for me (particularly, wrapping the return in a try/catch did nothing).

I have a few more details [where I first posted my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63458030/9948125), but the code is simple enough:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;
//...
public function mySometimesSoftDeletableRelation(){
    return $this->morphTo()->withoutGlobalScope(SoftDeletingScope::class);
}
```